# Openssl error while making http request

Tags: php, apache, openssl, tomcat7

I have two web applications just say webAppA and webAppB. webAppA is deployed in tomcat7 running  over https 8443. It provides RESTful services using basic authentication scheme. webAppB is php based web application which uses webAppA for authentication and to display some REST resources. It is deployed in apache2 over https 443. Whenever I try to make http request from webAppB to webAppA requesting is failing throwing open ssl exception below. Can anyone help me what might be wrong ? The code snippet from webAppB responsible for http connection is shown below.

```
/**
 * Check the username / password against the other webAppA$
 */
function webAppA_auth_check($username, $password) {

  require_once("auth-functions.php");
  require_once("HTTP/Request2.php");

  $bare_base_url = localhost
  // using basic authentication
  $url =  https://'.$username.':'.$password.'@'.$bare_base_url.':8443/app/ws/rest/v1/session';

  $request = new HTTP_Request2($url, HTTP_Request2::METHOD_GET);
  $request->setConfig(
      array(
          'ssl_verify_peer'   => false,
          'ssl_verify_host'   => false,
      )
  );
  try {
    $response = $request->send();
  } catch (HTTP_Request2_Exception $e) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
    exit();
  }
}
```

The exception is shown below.

```
Error: Unable to connect to ssl://123@localhost:8443. Error: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not knownstring(127) "Unable to connect to ssl://123@localhost:8443. Error: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known"
```

PS: username is dummy and password is dummy123

Comment: please enable ssl module in php.ini file 
`extension=php_openssl.dll`

Comment: I use linux, so I tried with php_openssl.so with no success :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply Use [Curl](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php%E2%80%8E) instead of http request

**example**

```
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  print_r($response);
```

Comment: I removed all HTTP/Request2.php. Curl works perfectly fine :)

Comment: Curl is a good tool for developers. its working in all platforms(linux & windows)